# Fresh Laravel 5.4, no debug information in responses

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I recently started working on a new Laravel application (5.4) but I'm not receiving any debug information in responses from API calls.
I have all the usual debug requirements checked:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:itMsUiBOOm4NsX4vJ72/XF9ktLkYWFLnQao9yVJkJSA=
APP_DEBUG=true
```

And I tried changing the permissions of the storage folder to 777 as it is suggested in many places on the internet.

The logs are saved correctly in the `laravel.log` file, but there is no trace of them in the API responses.

I will also add that I'm developing by serving the application via `php artisan serve` on MacOS Sierra and that all my other applications served this way work fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how do you call the api?

Comment: @onix I make all the requests through [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: so why do you expect the responses to be in the log file?

Comment: No I'm not expecting the responses to be in the log file, I'm expecting the debug information to be in the response.
I am expecting something like [this](https://snag.gy/RPUtru.jpg), but what I'm getting is [this](https://snag.gy/4wz2Bu.jpg)

Comment: the debug mode in laravel lets you see the exception in the browser.. make sure your `render` function in app>Exceptions>Handler.php returns this:  `return parent::render($request, $exception);`

Comment: I can confirm that my Exception handler is set to render the request and the exception: 

`return parent::render($request, $exception);`

Comment: does your config app.php look for your env file ? `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`

Comment: Yes, calling `config(app.debug)` also returns `true`.
If i run `php artisan env` I get `Current application environment: local`

Comment: Try to use `APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug` in your .env file

Comment: Still the same response as before even by setting in in `config/app.php`